# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning despite multiple try/catch blocks

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, try-catch, es6-promise

In working with the [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) module for Node and have been running into an oddball error when testing for errors. The sample code below runs just fine, connects to the database, then queries for the current user and waits one second in a loop. The error handling works if there is no connection *before* the loop starts and produces `console.error`:

```
2019-01-04T23:08:43.537Z 'Failed to connect to RNOD-EMSSQL:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND RNOD-EMSSQL'
```

However if the connection is killed (I've simply been turning off the adapter in Windows) *after* the loop has started, the error is not caught and produces:

```
(node:347996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to RNOD-EMSSQL:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND RNOD-EMSSQL
    at Connection.tedious.once.err (C:\Users\drodriguez\Desktop\POCs\mssql-issue\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:239:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\drodriguez\Desktop\POCs\mssql-issue\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1024:14)
    at C:\Users\drodriguez\Desktop\POCs\mssql-issue\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:868:25
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callback (C:\Users\drodriguez\Desktop\POCs\mssql-issue\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:69:18)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:69:17)
(node:347996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:347996) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm at a loss as to how/why this is occurring and is not getting caught by two different `try/catch` blocks and a `.catch` on the promise chain.

```js
const mssql = require('mssql');
const config = require('./config');

const test = async () => {
    // Reference to the connection
    let connection;

    // Flag to allow the do/while loop to run
    let run = true;

    try {
        // Establish a connection to the database
        connection = await mssql.connect(config.database);

        // Start the loop
        do {
            try {
                // Run a simple query to get the current user
                const results = await connection.request().query('SELECT CURRENT_USER AS [Name]');

                // Log it out to the console with the current date/time
                console.log(new Date(), results.recordset[0]);

                // Wait one second before restarting the loop
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
            } catch (error) {
                // If there is an error log it
                console.log(new Date(), error.message);

                // Break the loop
                run = false;
            }
        } while (run);
    } catch (error) {
        // If there is an error log it
        console.log(new Date(), error.message);
    } finally {
        // If a connection was established, close it out
        if (connection !== undefined) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}

// Run the test method
test()
.catch((error) => {
    // If there is an error log it
    console.log(new Date(), error.message);
})
```

EDIT: Removed the `new` keyword from script

Comment: I assume that `new mssql.connect(config.database)` returns a common Object rather than a Promise.Try `await mssql.connect(config.database)`

Comment: Ack! That was meant to be removed when I copy/pasted the code over, fixed the snippet.